# Colors with lollipop Android not appear like I choose

Tags: android, colors, android-5.0-lollipop

When I add color to button or layout or any view it appear good with phones which it's version less than 5.0.0 (Lollipop) but when i run with 5.0.0 (Lollipop) devices or above it appear some Light how can I solve this problem?
I add it normally add the color to res/values/color file then call it in view which I use I compile with version 6.0.0 for example

```
<color name="purple">#800080</color>
```

and in view background=@color/purple

Comment: Did you check the brightness level of your devices on which you tested it ? Is it same ?

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Comment: when i took screen shot and opened it on computer i found that colors like i want ?! so may be the problem with brightness ?